# cannot implement support design library in build gradle file

Tags: android

I'm trying to use Coordinator Layout in my xml file and found that it's corresponding libraries doesn't exists.

So i tried to include this in my gradle build file

> implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'

but it's giving the error

> Supplied String module notation 'androidx.' is invalid. Example notations: > 'org.gradle:gradle-core:2.2', 'org.mockito:mockito-core:1.9.5:javadoc'.

Then i found all support libraries is deprecated and one need to use androidx library.

> How to include this library in my gradle file ? 
>   `***My main intention is to use Coordinator Layout in my UI`

Comment: post your build.gradle

Comment: @vikas Archarya  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' you need to add this library also

Answer (score 1):

Click on "Refactor" on the android studio menu bar.
Select "Migrate to Androidx..."

Job Done.

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in saying that the support libraries have been deprecated. The new standard is AndroidX. [Here](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings) is a link that shows the current mappings from the old support libraries to AndroidX.

Specifically for CoordinatorLayout, it has gone from **com.android.support:coordinatorlayout** to **androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout**

Furthermore, I suggest reading this [page](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate) about migrating to AndroidX. It offers a lot of information and will make your transition to AndroidX much smoother.

Comment: Thank you but the fact is i'm very much new to android. Kindly tell me how to mention version for coordinatorlayout. Or give the proper code as it is to use in gradle build file.

Comment: I'm getting this error ERROR: Failed to resolve: androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:

Comment: You'll probably want to use this one, com.google.android.material:material-rc01

Comment: i end up with this 'androidx.coordinatorlayout:coordinatorlayout:1.0.0' . but what is  .material:material-rc01 does this have all layouts and components. so that i dont need to add one by one when needed ?

Comment: yes, it is the replacement for com.android.support:design

Comment: Thats what my question was ...!

Comment: it says failed to resolve. i cannot use com.google.android.material:material-rc01 in my project